# Data that references other data in assemble.io

Tags: json, assemble

I have data being pulled into assemble set-up like this:

```
 assemble: {
       options: {
         data: '<%= config.app %>/data/*',
```

To cut down on a lot of repetition, I'd like to include references to some data in other data, like so:

```
//in personnel.json
var Personnel = {
    "JohnStamos" : {
        "name":"John Stamos"
    }
}

// later on (in locations.json file -- maybe)...
[
    {
        "name": "TentTown",
        "personnel": [
            personnel.JohnStamos,
            personnel.GaryBusey
        ]
    }
]
```

I'm not sure how to reconcile that with the way assemble loads data, or if it's even reasonably possible. Is there a way to cross-reference data within the data files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*(Note that this information applies to v0.4.x assemble)*

Have you tried just using config templates? The same way you're doing in the gruntfile?

```
//in personnel.json
var personnel = {
  JohnStamos: {
    name: 'John Stamos'
  }
}

// later on (in locations.json file -- maybe)...
[{
  name: 'TentTown',
  personnel: [
    '<%= personnel.JohnStamos %>',
    '<%= personnel.GaryBusey %>'
  ]
}]
```

Comment: that's perfect. underscore templates? and it doesn't look like it matters what order they're defined in? can that be right? (assuming it generally does it alphabetically.. )

Comment: nope, doesn't matter the order. The templates are recursively resolved until  templates no longer exist.